# Употребление слова «популяция» как синоним «населения»

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, жаргон

> Впрочем, Рим с третьего и до середины XVI века совсем не похож на
>   столицу. Если в конце I века нашей эры источники указывают на
>   численность населения почти в семь миллионов, что подтверждают и
>   колоссальные строения древнего города, то после очередного
>   разграбления Рима, в 1527 году, его **популяция** (а канделябром? -
>   **Г. А.**) составит чуть более ста тысяч человек. То есть дееспособной его доли едва хватит, чтобы заполнить трибуны Колизея.

Верно ли употреблено выделенное слово?

Comment: Допустимо, но звучит как "научный канцеляризм". В данном контексте не уверен. А население в 7 млн. — это такая шутка?! Это верхняя оценка населения всего полуострова на то время, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Что-то неладно с временами, *указывают* и *составит*, *хватит*. Взгляд  из прошлого? Но *подтверждают* уже в наше время. Не здоровее ли все писать в прошедшем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русском языке термин ***популяция*** применяется человеку, но **в специальной литературе.** Возможно, в данном тексте это говорится не в прямом смысле, а с долей иронии. Как вариант, можно заключить *популяцию* в кавычки.

Из Интернета https://otvet.mail.ru/question/35060454

Популя́ция (от лат. populatio — население) — термин, используемый в различных разделах биологии, а также в генетике, демографии и медицине. Самый общий смысл заключается в дословном переводе. Популяция — это человеческое, животное или растительное население некоторой местности. **В европейских языках это понятие прежде всего относится к человеку** и уже во вторую очередь — к другим живым организмам. **В русском языке** популяция имеет более специальное значение как термин, преимущественно используемый в биологических и медицинских исследованиях.

Примеры

Судя по всему, катастрофическая ситуация с численностью человека прямоходящего сохранялась на протяжении примерно ми**ллиона лет ― до появления 160―200 тысяч лет назад Homo sapiens,** чья популяция в периоды резких изменений климата, к слову, тоже бывала весьма немногочисленна. [Во всем мире // «Знание - сила», 2010]

А вот сравнительный анализ ДНК современных людей позволять определить, как долго **популяция** живет в своем регионе. [обобщенный. У наших коллег // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, в данном контексте - это ошибка. Автор не совсем правильно понимает это слово.

Вот как трактуется это слово в Большом толковом словаре под редакцией Кузнецова.

**ПОПУЛЯЦИЯ, -и; ж. [от франц. population - население] Спец. Длительно существующая совокупность особей одного вида животных или растений. П. котиков. П. грызунов.**

Т. е. под популяцией понимаются представители (особи) только одного вида, а также длительное обитание этих самых видов на одной территории. Когда же речь идёт о представителях разных видов, это уже сообщество.

Обратите внимание: в словаре это слово снабжено пометой "спец". Т. е. - это термин относится более к биологии, нежели к экономике.